# How to use wc command with find and exec commands

Tags: bash

I use the following command to calculate md5sum for each file in the selected directory and log results to the file:

```
find $myDir -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; >> $myLog
```

I would like to also count processed element using `wc` command. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find "$myDir" -type f -exec md5sum {} + | tee -a -- "$myLog" | wc -l
```

`tee -a` will add the output of your `find` command to the file, and also to your stdout, where you can process it further, for instance with `wc -l` to count the number of lines in the input (and as `md5sum` escapes newline characters in file names as `\n`, that will also be the number of files that were processed).